# Update views from second Thread in Android Application

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-handler

In my application, two things are happening at once.  There is a clock hand `ImageView` in the activity that is constantly being turned, and the user can also press action bar buttons.  The updating of the clock's hand is drastically slowing down the performance of the app, and the buttons take several seconds to respond.  I need to be able to run the clock rotation on another thread, but so far I could not accomplish this.

The first thing I tried was to use a `Handler`:

```
class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity() {

  Handler handler;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    handler = new Handler();
    startRotation();
  }

  private void startRotation() {
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
      // do stuff to the UI here
    };

    handler.postDelayed(r, 100);
  }

}
```

But since that runs on `MainActivity`'s thread, it slowed everything down.

Next, I used an `AsyncTask`, but you can't update the UI from an AsyncTask without calling:

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {});
```

It still ran on the main thread and slowed the app down.

So my goal is this:  *To be able to update the clock's hand completely on one thread so that the main thread is used only for the user interaction, that way they both run smoothly.*

Thank You

**EDIT:**

My Code for rotating the clock's minute hand (updates every 100 millis):

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {

  ImageView minute_hand = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clock_hand_minute);
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
  float angle = 360f * ((float) c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60f);
  // minSdk is 11, so this works:
  minute_hand.setRotation(angle);

};
```

Comment: The first thing you tried would normally be the correct approach.  What are you doing to update the clock that's so computationally intensive?

Comment: I agree with Kevin Krumwlede's assessment. Could you post the code that's responsible for drawing the clock hand?

Comment: If you are simply just changing images, then you should do any image loading and image-work in an asynctask and then set the image you created to the imageview on the ui thread. Setting an image in the UI thread should not cause lag. Now, calculating all the pixels and changing stuff like that COULD potentially... Also, you are only updating at 10 frames per second, the UI should be able to handle that no problem... your image changing technique must be extremely expensive...

Comment: Try to declare the minute_hand and the calendar object one time and not every time r is run. Then I would have tried the AsyncTask approach but do all the calculations in the background thread and then set the rotation in runOnUIThread. If that doesn't work, have you tried animations on your ImageView objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're executing this code:

```
ImageView minute_hand = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.clock_hand_minute);
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
float angle = 360f * ((float) c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) / 60f);
minute_hand.setRotation(angle);
```

every 100ms, then I'd say it's overkill.

In general, note that since this code runs in the UI thread every 100ms, whatever time slice it consumes will be removed from the time necessary for the UI to respond to user interaction. Therefore, it should be as fast as possible!

First of all, you should move the `findViewById(R.id.clock_hand_minute)` code outside the runnable. Calling it once at the start should be enough, since the view doesn't change.

Secondly, when a minute elapses, the minute hand moves 6 degrees, which is correct. However, you're doing this every 100ms, or 600 times per minute. This means that the view is being updated for **very** small rotations each time (one hundredth of a degree) which are probably nearly invisible to the naked eye, but time-consuming in terms of drawing.

It would probably be much better if you set a minimum threshold for updating the angle. Something like

```
if (angle - lastAngle > THRESHOLD)
    minute_hand.setRotation(angle);
```